# Getting the background color of a cell in an existing Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, perl, scripting, report

I am trying to read an existing Excel spreadsheet and write it into a new Excel document with all the same format options.

I am able to read the cell contents and write them into the new Excel sheet, but I cannot get the background color of the cell.

If I use the `$cell->get_format->{Fill}[2]` method it gives me numbers like either 64 or 65 if the cell has a background color.

How can I get the actual color of a cell and apply the same background color to the cell in new Excel sheet?

I am doing all these things as there is no method available in the `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` module to set the background color for a cell after appending data to an existing Excel sheet.

Here is my code

```perl
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser          = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook_parse  = $parser->Parse( 'Report.xls' );
my $worksheet_parse = $workbook_parse->Worksheet( "Health_Report" );
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_parse->col_range();
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_parse->row_range();

my $workbook   = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( "Report_new.xls" );
my $worksheet  = $workbook->addworksheet( "Health_Report" );
my $bkgd_color = $workbook->addformat();

for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

        # Return the cell object at $row and $col

        my $cell = $worksheet_parse->get_cell( $row, $col );
        next unless $cell;

        my $value           = $cell->value();
        my $format          = $cell->get_format();
        my $backgroundcolor = $format->{Fill}->[2];

        print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col) ";
        print "Value       = $value\n";
        print "Format      = $backgroundcolor\n";

        $bkgd_color->set_bg_color( $backgroundcolor );

        ### Here trying to rewrite into Excel and apply the
        ### same background color which the cell had previously

        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value, $bkgd_color );
    }
}
```

Part of my output from print statements:

```
Format      = 65
Row, Col    = (25, 4) Value       = -115966
Format      = 65
Row, Col    = (10, 5) Value       = 20170417
Format      = 65
Row, Col    = (11, 5) Value       = 0
Format      = 64
Row, Col    = (16, 5) Value       = 0
Format      = 64
```

Comment: Please try to keep your code tidy, especially before asking for help with it. It helps enormously to follow a program if it is properly indented and laid out. I have done it for you this time, and I hope you can see the improvement? Please also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. It is your first line of defence against basic errors and mistakes and should never be omitted even in the simplest of programs.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

It appears that the documentation is wrong. The name of the workbook object method is different from that of the class method, and you need to call

```
$workbook->color_idx_to_rgb($color_index)
```

instead

---

The [documentation for `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#$font-%3E%7BColor%7D) says this

> **$font->{Color}**
>
> Returns the color index for the font. The mapping to an RGB color is defined by each workbook.
>
> The index can be converted to a RGB string using the `$workbook->ColorIdxToRGB()` Parser method.
>
> (Older versions of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` provided the `ColorIdxToRGB` class method, which is deprecated.)

I expect that the colour indexes in the `$format->{Fill}` array can be translated similarly

Comment: Borodin:I tried using  ColorIdxToRGB  and it gives me  error:                                  Can't locate object method "ColorIdxToRGB" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook"

Comment: @Venkateshk: I imagine that you have an old copy of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`. What is the output of `perl -MSpreadsheet::ParseExcel -E 'say Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->VERSION'`?

Comment: @Venkateshk: Please see the update to my answer. I've looked at the source of the module, and it seems that the documentation is wrong. You need to call `$workbook->color_idx_to_rgb($color_index)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Hello [Venkatesh k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6076762/venkatesh-k),

Try the [set_color()](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#set_color()) method from ([Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#set_color())).

From the documentation:

> ```
>  Default state:      Excels default color, usually black
>  Default action:     Set the default color
>  Valid args:         Integers from 8..63 or the following strings:
>                     'black'
>                     'blue'
>                     'brown'
>                     'cyan'
>                     'gray'
>                     'green'
>                     'lime'
>                     'magenta'
>                     'navy'
>                     'orange'
>                     'pink'
>                     'purple'
>                     'red'
>                     'silver'
>                     'white'
>                     'yellow'
> ```

**Update:** try this, it seems to be working for my example spread sheet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

sub create_new_worksheet {
    my ($row, $col, $value, $backgroundcolor) = @_;

    # Create a new Excel workbook
    my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');

    # Add a worksheet
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

    #  Add and define a format
    my $format = $workbook->add_format(bg_color => $backgroundcolor);
    $format->set_align('center');

    # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
    $worksheet->write($row, $col, $value, $format);
}

my $parser          = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook_parse  = $parser->Parse( 'Report.xls' );
my $worksheet_parse = $workbook_parse->Worksheet("Sheet1");
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet_parse->col_range();
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet_parse->row_range();

for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

    # Return the cell object at $row and $col

    my $cell = $worksheet_parse->get_cell( $row, $col );
    next unless $cell;

    my $value           = $cell->value();
    my $format          = $cell->get_format();
    my $backgroundcolor = $format->{Fill}->[2];

    print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col) ";
    print "Value       = $value\n";
    print "Format      = $backgroundcolor\n";

    create_new_worksheet($row, $col, $value, $backgroundcolor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanos:Thanx for the answer.But I am not looking for setting the font color. I am looking for to read a background color of a cell and apply the same background color to the cell which is in new Spreadsheet.Background color of a cell can be set through set_bg_color() of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.The thing is when I am reading the background color throuh $format->{Fill}[2] method I am getting 65(if no bg color) or 64 irrespective of the background color.

Comment: @Venkateshk take a look on the update solution. Try it and let me know if it also works for you.

Comment: The "palette"—the mapping between a colour index and an actual colour value—is specific to each spreadsheet. You can't just copy colour indexes from one spreadsheet to another and expect the same result.

Comment: @Borodin correct if I am wrong, but the OP wants to read and parse an excel file and create an "alternate/copy" of the same xls file format. So why not using the same index?

Comment: @Thanos: That's what I was trying to explain. You can use the same index, but there's no way of knowing what actual colour it will map to in the new Excel workbook. It may be the same colour, but there's no guarantee. That's why the the module has been changed from using a class method `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->ColorIdxToRGB($colour_index)` to a workbook object method `$workbook->color_idx_to_rgb($color_index)`.

Comment: @Borodin: I understand your point but I am facing a problem. I get the color from `my $sRGB_2 = $workbook->color_idx_to_rgb($format->{Fill}->[2]);` but when I set the color in hex format e.g. (`ffff00`) with the method `add_format(bg_color => "ffff00")` it does not create the correct background color, but when I define it like `add_format(bg_color => $format->{Fill}->[2])` works just fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Thanos: If you have a problem of your own then please post a question, giving as much detail as possible. You shouldn't hijack someone else's thread. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not a chat forum.